# Email Accounts not showing up in CPanel, But the folders listed in Filemanager

Tags: email, cpanel

Iam using cPanel for managing my websites and Email accounts. Suddenly all the email accounts belongs to my domain got disappear from Email accounts but i can view the folders in Filemanager (/home/user/mail).

I didn't done anything before this error happen. please help me to solve this issue because some important mails inside that email IDS and i don't have any backup.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Finally i have found the solution for my own question myself.

I have found entries got missing for the mail accounts got disappear In **shadow** file. Email accounts start visible after copied the entries from the backup file **shadow.roottn.bak**.

File Location : **/home/cpanelusername/etc/domainname.com/**

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the .bak file as suggested by @Sathya, but I was able to get accounts showing up on new server by simply copying the entire **cpanelusername** directory in **/home/cpanelusername/etc/domainname.com/** and uploading to the new server.